# How to override woocommerce cart calculate_totals function?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

How to override woocommerce cart calculate_totals function?
I have to change logic of calculate_totals function without change in core class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create function in your theme's function file & add woocommerce total action -

Here is the sample code -

```
function my_function_name($woocommerce_cart_object)
{
   //your code here
}
add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'my_function_name');
```